# Should you set async true or use jQuery beforeunload to prevent users leaving during a file upload?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

If your using a mix of jQuery and Ajax to manage the front-end of a user upload form like this:

```
$('form :button').click(function(){

    var formData = new FormData($("form")[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/upload',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        data: formData,
        success: function (res) {
            alert("Uploaded");
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Would it make sense to use `async:false` to stop all browser movement until the upload is complete or use some sort of jQuery function, like `beforeunload` to notify users that leaving the page would interrupt their upload?

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    return 'If you leave this page, your upload will not complete! Continue?';
});
```

Is there an option in Ajax to only run a function while the upload is in progress so that this warning only appears during the file upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably better to save a flag on the start of the upload process:

```
$('form :button').click(function(){

    var formData = new FormData($("form")[0]);
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('uploading', true);

    $.ajax({
       ..., // your attributes
       success: function (res) {
           $this.data('uploading', false);
           alert("Uploaded");
       },
    ... // rest of your code
});
```

Then on `beforeunload`

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    if($('form :button').data('uploading') === true) {
       return 'If you leave this page, your upload will not complete! Continue?';
    }
});
```